# Uncaught Type Error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am working on my first SignalR code, and I am running into an uncaught type error. My code initially works, as my hub controller returns a serialized array back to the client. The problem occurs when I try to iterate through the array using the $.each() method. The exact error I receive is this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '95' in
>   [{"OptionsId":3,"MembershipLevel":"Gold","MembershipLevelId":2,"Days":0,"Months":1,"Fee":20.00}]

I don't know what this means, so I am not sure if this is SignalR related, jQuery, or something else.  Here is my code.

jQuery:

```
var getOptions = function () {
// reference the auto generated proxy for the hub
var vR = $.connection.vendorRegistration;

// create the function that the hub can call back to update option
vR.client.updateMembershipOptions = function (returnOptions) {
    // update the selectList
    $("select[name=SelectedMembershipOption]").empty();

    // this is where I receive the error
    $.each(returnOptions, function (index, memOption) {
        $("select[name=SelectedMembershipOption]").append(
            $("<option/>").attr("value", memOption.OptionsId)
              .text(memOption.MembershipLevel)
            );
    });
};

// Start the connection
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $("#VendorType").change(function () {
        // call the ReturnMembershipOptions method on the hub
        vR.server.returnMembershipOptions($("#VendorType")
            .val());
    });
});
};
```

Server Side:

```
public class VendorRegistration : Hub
{
    public void ReturnMembershipOptions(int vendorTypeId)
    {
        // get the options
        var options = AcoadRepo.Vendors.ApiLogic.MembershipOptions
            .ReturnOptions(vendorTypeId);

        // serialize the options
        var returnOptions = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options);

        // call the updateMembershipOptions method to update the client
        Clients.All.updateMembershipOptions(returnOptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the error that you are is because you're trying to traverse a string.  The reason why it's trying to traverse a string is because of this line:

```
// serialize the options
var returnOptions = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options);
```

SignalR will serialize your object for you, so since you're serializing in your hub method the data that's going over the wire is double serialized which then represents a plain string, therefore when it hits the client it's deserialized as a string.

Performing a .each on a string will throw because it requires that the calling argument is either an array or an object.

**To fix** your issue just remove your serialization and just call the function with your options, aka:

```
public class VendorRegistration : Hub
{
    public void ReturnMembershipOptions(int vendorTypeId)
    {
        // get the options
        var options = AcoadRepo.Vendors.ApiLogic.MembershipOptions
            .ReturnOptions(vendorTypeId);

        // call the updateMembershipOptions method to update the client
        Clients.All.updateMembershipOptions(options);
    }
}
```